# Python numpy - fill numpy array with ascending values

Tags: python, list, numpy

I am trying to initialize a `numpy array` or a `list` with ascending values. The number of values is `n`.

e.g: If `n = 10`

```
[0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18]
```

If `n = 2`

```
[0,2]
```

I am aware that I could use a `for` like this:

```
result = []
for x in range(n):
   result.append(x*2)
```

But when `n` gets larger this would take a while so I was looking for a faster way.

Comment: try `np.arange()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is [`numpy.arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) which supports a `step` parameter:

```py
result = np.arange(0, 2*n, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, for a list you can use [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#range)'s step parameter:

```py
result = list(range(0, 2*n, 2))
```